# Combine elements in a nested list - Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python3 Concatenating lists within lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542794/python3-concatenating-lists-within-lists)

I have

```
Nested_List = [['John', 'Smith'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

I want to manipulate this list such that I get this output:

```
Nested_List = [['John Smith'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

Basically the two elements in the first list were combined. How do I do this?

Comment: This is my first time posting a question on this forum.

Comment: Are you the same person as... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542794/python3-concatenating-lists-within-lists

Comment: No, but it's a great coincidence.

Comment: @Azh look at the pre-edit posts. I'm about 99% sure it's the same person.

Comment: So he wants us to do his homework while he duplicates accounts rather than trying to learn or at the least, changing up the examples? Hm.

Comment: We can do 2 things here. We can have a long argument about my identity, or you can be helpful and answer my question. And I am not the same person. I've said that twice now, I will not say it again.

Comment: What's special about the first list that you want its elements combined, and not the elements of the other list? Will you always have strings? Define "combine".

Answer (score 0):

```
newElement = [' '.join(NestedList[0])]
Nested_List[0] = newElement
```

(modifies list, bad practice, but simple)

Comment: agf: oops, thank you, changed